# Status bar transparent on android with nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, statusbar

I would like to know how can I set the status bar on transparent on Android with Nativescript ?

I read many post ([How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android), https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-transparent-activity-in-android...) but the status bar is always Grey or not transparence.

> In values/styles.xml I added this :

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

> In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar">
```

I'm confuse because it's like very easy. Maybe it's different on nativescript ?

I look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NroxMDGOJ_E but if I set this color "#00000000" or "@android:color/transparent" on ns_primaryDark it doesn't work.

Comment: Just setting `android:windowIsTranslucent` to `true` in styles xml works perfectly on my end. If you have issues, please share a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

- page.xml
- page.js
- page.css

Tested in Nativescript 6, Try this in your page's corresponding nativescript CSS file:

```
ActionBar {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

0 here is complete transparency, where 0.5 is half transparent, and 1 is show the Actionbar completely.

A clean way to hide the actionbar is to just go to the javascript page, though:

```
exports.loaded = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
```

and in your XML page we add the loaded function that will receive the event, and the page, and hide that pages actionbar based on the attribute of "actionBarHidden":

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
<Page>
```

Comment: Thank you @gnu_byte, but I would like to set the satus bar on transparent and not the actionbar :-)

Comment: @JérémieChazelle are you referring to the phone UI's status bar that normally lives above the action bar?

Comment: @gnu_bytes yes !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be of some help then?

https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar

```
// Get reference to the Status Bar plugin module
import statusBar = require("nativescript-status-bar");

exports.loaded = function() {
    statusBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: I would like to have a background transparent and no hide the status bar

Comment: @JérémieChazelle Did you find any solution?